# Using pure Python over grep?

Tags: python, grep, sublimetext3

I am not familiar with `grep` as I've always been on a Windows system so when someone suggested I add these lines to my code, I'm a little confused...

```
grep = 'grep -E \'@import.*{}\' * -l'.format(name)
proc = Popen(grep, shell=True, cwd=info['path'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

From my understanding, this is trying to find all files in `cwd` that contain `@import given_file_name` essentially, right?

If this is how `grep` works, I would need to write something in just Python that would do this for me, however I'm worried about the time it may take to do such a thing.

The script is in a Sublime Text 3 plugin that runs the `sublime_plugin.EventListener` method `on_post_save` to find all files containing the just saved filename and build a list of file names to compile.

```
def files_that_import(filename, project_root):
    files = []
    for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(project_root):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.endswith(('.scss', '.sass')):
                with open(fn, 'r') as f:
                    data = f.read()
                if re.search(r'@import.*["\']{}["\'];'.format(fn), data):
                    files.append(fn)
    return files
```

Not knowing exactly how `grep` works, this was the best I could think of. However, like I said, I'm worried about the time it would take to scan through all `.scss` and `.sass` files. While there shouldn't be a ton of them, getting the contents for each seems like it's more complicated than what it could be.

**updated**

I updated the code using @nneonneo corrections. I also noticed in the code I used, it was checking each file for an `@import` statement for itself.

```
def files_that_import(filename, project_root):
    pattern = re.compile('''@import.*["']{}["'];'''.format(filename))
    found = []
    for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(project_root):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.endswith(('.scss', '.sass')):
                with open(fn, 'r') as f:
                    if any(pattern.search(line) for line in f):
                        found.append(fn)
    return found
```

**update**
If anyone finds this useful and wants to use the code, I changed `files = []` to `found = []` since `files` is being defined in the for loop with `os.walk()` causing an error.

Comment: You can use `if any(pattern.search(line) for line in f):files.append(fn)` instead of the three lines and break, there are also many implementations of grep for windows http://superuser.com/questions/300815/command-prompt-windows-7-grep-equivalent

Comment: The issue I'm running into with trying to make this pure python is that this a hosted Sublime Text plugin and I felt anyone using it should not be required to install additional software in order to make this work for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mostly got it. You can make it a bit more efficient by doing the following:

```
import_pattern = re.compile(r'''@import.*["']{}["'];'''.format(fn))
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if import_pattern.match(line):
            files.append(fn)
            break
```

This will scan through each line, and break as soon as it finds what it is looking for. It should be faster than reading the whole file.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I didn't even think about just checking by line! Most of the time the `@import` statements are at the top, so hopefully this would speed it up a lot!